# Django cloudinary image how to add onClick event in template {% %} tag?

Tags: django, cloudinary

I am successfully creating a Cloudinary image as follows:

```
{% cloudinary photo.filename 
    width='300' 
    crop='fill' 
    class='item_photo' 
    id=photo.filename %}
```

Which results in html img tag:

```
<img 
    class="item_photo" 
    id="xxxxxx"         
    width="300"
    src="https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload/c_fill,w_300/vxxx/xxx.jpg">
```

However, I want to add an `onClick` event to the img, but am not able to figure out the correct syntax or perhaps even if it is possible.

I would like html tag to look like:

```
<img 
    class="item_photo" 
    id="xxxxxx"         
    width="300"
    onClick=imageClick('xxxxxx')  <=== event variable is same as `id` value
    src="https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload/c_fill,w_300/vxxx/xxx.jpg">
```

The `id` and `imageClick` variable are themselves populated by Django template tag value `photo.filename`.

Some things I've tried:

onClick='photoClick(photo.filename)' %}

{% with add:'onClick=photoClick('{{ photo.filename }}|add:') as onclick %}{{ onclick }}{% endwith %}

|add:'onClick=photoClick('{{ photo.filename }}|add:')'  %}

How can I construct the `onClick=photoClick(xxx)` part of this template tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the *onClick* attribute to the *img* tag as shown below (e.g. *photo.filename=sample_image*):

```
{% cloudinary photo.filename width="300" crop="fill" class="item_photo" id=photo.filename onclick="photoClick(this)" %}
```

Add the script function *photoClick()*, which can accept the *img* tag object that can be processed as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function photoClick(img) {
        
        console.log("The src data is: " + img.src);
        console.log("The id data is: " + img.id);
        
        var filename = img.src.substring(img.src.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        console.log("The filename is: " + filename);
        
        // Other actions
        var src = img.src;
        window.open(src);
    }
</script>
```

The resulting HTML  tag will be:

```
<img class="item_photo" id="sample_image" onclick="photoClick(this)" src="https://<your_cloudinary_image_url_path>/sample_image.<ext>" width="300"/>
```